# More covert rf remote shutter control for canon Xsi?

Tags: canon, remote

I am looking for a more covert *(not illegal, I want to take pics of myself while doing a play)* remote than one where you take it out of your pocket and it's handsized, and then you pull out a giant silver radio stick for it to work.

Does anyone know of an rf shutter control remote with about 150 feet of range that does not have a silver radio stick and is compatible with a Canon Xsi?

thank you very much for any help!!!

Comment: I'd first see if the antenna needs to be extended at the range you want to use the remote.  if it does then you can remove the antenna and replace it with a line piece of jacketed wire,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider using RF flash triggers. Most of them can connect the sync port output of a receiver unit to your camera's shutter cable release port via a cable (e.g., PC -> 2.5mm minijack if you're using a Canon dRebel model), and you simply use the transmitter as your in-hand remote.

None of the transmitter units, as far as I know, have a telescoping antenna on them (if that's what you mean by "giant silver radio stick").  I've used Yongnuo RF-602 triggers as shutter remotes. An RF-603II or RF-605 can be used the same way, and they'll also double-duty as remote flash triggers.  They will have less capability than a dedicated RF shutter release, but you can get half-press and full press, the range is good, and the units are generally pretty small and discreet.

Comment: Does the Yongnuo RF-602 work with Canon Xsi?

Comment: @JeremyH I've updated the first paragraph to describe how you use it, and how it can be compatible with a Canon XSi. You just need the right cable. However, I wouldn't get the RF-602s--they're an older model with separate Rx/Tx units, that uses a weird-size CR2 battery in the Tx unit. The RF-603II is a more updated model and a better choice--particularly if you choose to use these as flash remotes later on. They run off standard AAA batteries, and the units are transceivers (i.e., can be either an Rx or Tx).

Comment: Thank  you for your help so far. Does this product                                            http://www.amazon.com/YONGNUO-Wireless-Shutter-RF-603II-C3/dp/B00NL4ZNO0/ref=sr_1_4?ie=UTF8&qid=1449193350&sr=8-4&keywords=RF-603II                                                                                          include the right cable?

Comment: you get the bounty once I can award it. :)

Comment: @JeremyH No, you need the C1 cable, not the C3. Both connectors should be 2.5mm minijacks, iirc.